# Set current element in onclick event handler loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looping over multiple elements, which I'd like to assign an onclick event handler too.

The problem is that the element sent to the goTo function (event handler), is always the last element in the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation');

    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        var navLink = navLinks[i];
        navLink.onclick = function() { goTo.call(navLink); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a closure, like this:

```
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation');

for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    var navLink = navLinks[i];
    (function(navLink){   //This line does the magic
         navLink.onclick = function() { goTo.call(navLink); }  
    })(navLink);  //This calls the created function      
}
```

This way, the inner `navLink` will be unique per loop cycle, so it won't get overwritten (that's why it remained with the latest value in your previous code)

Cheers

Comment: I know this is old, but the solution is *not* to "add a closure". The solution works because a function is *executed*, thus creating a new scope. Whether the function is a closure or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196) for an explanation.

Inside the event handler you can access the element itself via `this` (this works also if you used `addEventListener` to bind the handler instead):

```
navLink.onclick = function() { goTo.call(this); }
```

And assuming `goTo` is a function, you can shorten the code to

```
navLink.onclick = goTo;
```

in your case.